# Sass function to call more than one Palette

Tags: sass

I am using sass palettes and I would like know how can I make this function works for more than 1 palettes.

right now I can just use 1 palette with this function, how can make this function works for more than 1 palette?

```
@function palette($palette, $shade: 'base') {
  @return map-get(map-get($color-palettes, $palette), $shade);
}



$primary-palette: (
    grey: (
        xx-light : lighten($grey, 43%),
        x-light  : lighten($grey, 35%),
        light    : lighten($grey, 6%),
        base     : $grey,
        dark     : darken($grey, 8%),
        x-dark   : darken($grey, 16%)
    ),  
);
```

**// will be my secondary paletter**

```
  $secondary-palette: (
            black: (
                light    : lighten($grey, 6%),
                base     : $grey,
                dark     : darken($grey, 8%),
                x-dark   : darken($grey, 16%)
            ),  
        );
```

**applied in the css**

```
body {
  background-color: palette(grey,dark);
}
```

Someone can help?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've not done anything like this before, but it looks really powerful. I did some searching and [this article seems to suggest you'd put the `black` palette within `$primary-palette` as well](http://blog.bugsnag.com/sass-color-palettes#leveraging-the-power-of-sass-maps), only having one master set of palettes.

From the post:

```
$colors: (
  blue: (
    0: hsl(198, 74%, 49%),
    1: hsl(200, 72%, 61%),
    2: hsl(200, 71%, 73%),
    [...]
  ),
  red: (
    0: hsl(3, 72%, 62%),
    1: hsl(4, 85%, 66%),
    2: hsl(4, 84%, 78%),
    [...]
  )
)


@function get-color($color, $value: 0) {
    @return map-get(map-get($colors, $color), $value);
}


.button--blue{
  color: get-color(blue, 0);
  background: get-color(blue, 4);
  &:hover{
    background: get-color(blue, 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, I really need to try this out. I think I'd seen it in the docs but was initially intimidated. Power user stuff.